# Jquery photo array easy fade

Tags: jquery, arrays, fadein, fadeout, photos

I have a div with multiple background-images.  I also have a script to change those images every X seconds.  I just want to add a simple fade transition, instead of the instant change I get with this script alone.  Can I just add a simple line of code to make this work?  Your help is greatly appreciated.  I am a beginner!  Heres the script:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var now = 0;
var int = self.setInterval("changeBG()", 2000);
var array = ["jar1.jpg", "field.jpg",];

function changeBG(){
    //array of backgrounds
    now = (now+1) % array.length ;
    $('#maincontent').css('background-image', 'url("photos/' + array[now] + '")');

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David!

saw your comment in the other question, thought I might as well have a look. A 'simple' way of cross-fading in jQuery is described in the following link, maybe that can help you on your way?

http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Good luck

Comment: Wow thanks!  After a bit of tweaking I managed to implement that!  Thank you very very much!

Comment: Only problem is that script runs once then stops at the last image.  How can I get it to refresh at the top of the list again?

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled onto that one as well. I think you have to check if it's the last image in the row/list, (check .next('file/element-type')) and if not, go to first (.first()). You can find the exact markup on the jQuery site!